# Locked orientation overridden by Youtube Player Flutter

Tags: flutter

I restricted my app for only portrait mode. The orientation was locked until I played a video full screen within my app with Youtube [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter). Once I exit the video, the app now can go landscape orientation as well if I tilt my phone.

Below code, I used for orientation restriction:

```
void main() {
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
.then((_) {
  runApp(new MyApp());
});
}
```

Any Ideas, how can I keep the orientation locked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this on dispose:

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: Yes, that I figured lately. Thank you though for answering here.

Answer (score 2):

Using 
`SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);` 
on `build` method

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
    return MaterialApp(...);
   }
```

Comment: You must insert it in all the builds of all the widgets, otherwise you should manage it natively

Answer (score 1):

If you not want to go back from whole screen just change the orientation on back button use the given below code:

```
Future<bool> _checkForLandscape(BuildContext ctx) async {
if (MediaQuery.of(ctx).orientation == Orientation.landscape) {
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    [
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ],
  );
  _controller.toggleFullScreenMode();
  return false;
}
return true;
```

}

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => _checkForLandscape(context),
      child: _anyChild());}
```